# Input string was not in a correct format. using MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I had a code that was working the past few weeks and am getting an ERROR "Input string was not in a correct format"

**NB:(MVC Asp.net)**

the view gets data from the Razor page URL and Execute a query

the URL is like this: https://localhost:44348/Devices/Details/5?typeName=Dongle

and the following the View code :

```
    public ActionResult Details(string typeName, int? id)
    {
        var sql = "SELECT A.*," +
             " COALESCE(ps.first_name, '') as firstname," +
             " COALESCE(ps.last_name, '') as lastname," +
             " COALESCE(p.program_name, '') as program_Name, " +
             " COALESCE(l.loan_date, '') as loan_date, " +
             " COALESCE(l.return_date, '') as return_date" +
             " FROM devices A" +
             " LEFT JOIN device_loans l on l.device_id = A.device_id" +
             " LEFT JOIN persons ps on ps.person_id = l.person_id" +
             " LEFT JOIN programs p on A.program_id = p.program_id" +
             " WHERE A.device_type = '" + typeName + "' and p.program_id = "+ id +";";

        var devices = _context.DeviceDetails
            .FromSqlRaw(sql)
            .ToList();

        return View(devices);
    }
```

I have tried Passing parameters with parameter placeholders but still not working

please help.

Comment: Please use parameterized sql command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Because your parameter id: is nullable, you need  combine sql like:

```
var sql = "SELECT A.*," +
     " COALESCE(ps.first_name, '') as firstname," +
     " COALESCE(ps.last_name, '') as lastname," +
     " COALESCE(p.program_name, '') as program_Name, " +
     " COALESCE(l.loan_date, '') as loan_date, " +
     " COALESCE(l.return_date, '') as return_date" +
     " FROM devices A" +
     " LEFT JOIN device_loans l on l.device_id = A.device_id" +
     " LEFT JOIN persons ps on ps.person_id = l.person_id" +
     " LEFT JOIN programs p on A.program_id = p.program_id" +
     " WHERE A.device_type = '" + typeName + "'";
     
if(id!=null){
 sql += " and p.program_id = "+ id +";";
 }
```

BTW: your code has SQL injection risk

Comment: if you still want combine sql, you must replace single quot like : `typeName = typeName.Replace("'", "''");`